# How to deploy action cable on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, actioncable

Hi i have implemented action cable using rails 5. its working fine locally but its not working on heroku. on heroku whenever i send any message it sends four messages, two duplicates and 2 blank messages. here is my code :-
conversation.js

```
 App.conversation = App.cable.subscriptions.create("ConversationChannel", {
      connected: function() {},
      disconnected: function() {},
      received: function(data) {
        var conversation = $('#conversations-list').find("[data-conversation-id='" + data['conversation_id'].$oid + "']");
        if (data['window'] !== undefined) {
          var conversation_visible = conversation.is(':visible');

          if (conversation_visible) {
            var messages_visible = (conversation).find('.panel-body').is(':visible');

            if (!messages_visible) {
              conversation.removeClass('panel-default').addClass('panel-success');
              conversation.find('.panel-body').toggle();
            }
            conversation.find('.messages-list').find('ul').append(data['message']);
          }
          else {
            $('#conversations-list').append(data['window']);
            conversation = $('#conversations-list').find("[data-conversation-id='" + data['conversation_id'].$oid + "']"); 
            conversation.find('.panel-body').toggle();
          }
        }
        else {
          conversation.find('ul').append(data['message']);
        }

        var messages_list = conversation.find('.messages-list');
        var height = messages_list[0].scrollHeight;
        messages_list.scrollTop(height);
      },
      speak: function(message) {
        return this.perform('speak', {
          message: message
        });
      },
    });

$(document).on('submit', '.new_message', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var values = $(this).serializeArray();
  App.conversation.speak(values);
  $(this).trigger('reset');
});
```

Application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require rails-ujs
// require turbolinks
//= require jquery-3.2.1.min
// require_tree .

(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.toggle-window', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var panel = $(this).parent().parent();
    var messages_list = panel.find('.messages-list');

    panel.find('.panel-body').toggle();
    panel.attr('class', 'panel panel-default');

    if (panel.find('.panel-body').is(':visible')) {
      var height = messages_list[0].scrollHeight;
      messages_list.scrollTop(height);
    }
  });
})();
```

Cable.js

```
//= require action_cable
    //= require_self
    //= require_tree ./channels

        (function() {
          this.App || (this.App = {});

          App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();

        }).call(this);
```

create.js

```
var conversations = $('#conversations-list');
var conversation = conversations.find("[data-conversation-id='" + "<%= @conversation.id %>" + "']");

        if (conversation.length !== 1) {
          conversations.append("<%= j(render 'conversations/conversation', conversation: @conversation, user: current_user) %>");
          conversation = conversations.find("[data-conversation-id='" + "<%= @conversation.id %>" + "']");
        }

        conversation.find('.panel-body').show();

        var messages_list = conversation.find('.messages-list');
        var height = messages_list[0].scrollHeight;
        messages_list.scrollTop(height);
```

Chat Screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eXmt.png)

Please let me know how i can fix it. i am using rails 5 with ruby-2.4.0. i am also using redis server for jobs.

Comment: You need to add the error message  a specific problem statement to the question. What did you expect to happen? What went wrong? What have you attempted to remedy the the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You set a Javascript `event` listener that has nothing to do with ActionCable.

Every time you trigger the `submit` bottom you call the `App.conversation.speak()` function that append the message on the page

```
$(document).on('submit', '.new_message', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var values = $(this).serializeArray();
  App.conversation.speak(values);
  $(this).trigger('reset');
});
```

this is your `speak` function

```
speak: function(message) {
   return this.perform('speak', {
     message: message
   });
```

I quote [`Defining The Channel's Subscriber`](https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable#step-1-define-the-channel)

> We add our new subscription to our consumer with `App.cable.subscriptions.create`. We give this function an argument of the name of the channel to which we want to subscribe, `ConversationChannel`.
>
> When this `subscriptions.create` function is invoked, it will invoke the `ConversationChannel#subscribed` method, which is in fact a **callback method**.

[**So what is a callback method?**](https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable#step-1-define-the-channel) I can't answer clearly this question.

> This method is responsible for subscribing to and streaming messages that are broadcast to this channel.

app/channels/conversation_channel.rb

```
class ConversationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel  
  def subscribed
    stream_from 'conversation'
  end
end
```

that

> `ConversationChannel#subscribed` streams from our messages broadcast, sending along any new messages as JSON to the client-side subscription function.

This is how I implement ActionCable, after the `Message` is saved to the db I trigger the following action in my `MessagesController` as in [Sophie Debenedetto](http://sophiedebenedetto.nyc/) guide (I don't know if you save a `Conversation` to the DB or a `Message`)

> app/controllers/messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    message = Message.new(message_params)
    message.user = current_user
    if message.save
      ActionCable.server.broadcast 'messages',
        message: message.content,
        user: message.user.username
      head :ok
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

`ActionCable.server.broadcast 'messages',` sends a call to the `received` function inside `App.cable.subscription` and that function is responsible for updating the page with the new message.

This call will be performed only for the user that are `subscribed` to this event. The subscriptions are managed in the `subscribed` method of the `ConversationChannel`

```
App.conversation = App.cable.subscriptions.create('ConversationChannel', {      
  received: function(data) {
      $('#messages').append(this.speak(data));
      },
  speak: function(data) {
      return "<br><p> <strong>" + data.user + ": </strong>" + data.message + "</p>";
      };
  }
});
```

It passed the following data from your rails controller in the `json` format `message: message.content, user: message.user.username`

Some of this code is taken from my app https://sprachspiel.xyz that is an action cable app you can test, the app should be still working. This is the [github repository](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/sprachspiel)

I believe you are calling your js function twice, or doing some workaround to make actioncable work that causes the div to be appended twice. I believe your are executing 2 different time js to run action cable.

Remember that action cable is a websocket meant to update that message on 2 different users/browsers